# Combine multiple xts-objects into a array with considering of the columns

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, xts, quantmod

Hi guys i'm wondering if there is a possibility to add multiple xts-objects into a 3-D-Array.

I want to put multiple Stock-Data from quantmod together in an (n x m x 4) array. the 4 is for respective close, open, high, low price of the stocks.

So at the end i want to have like 4 data-frames in 1 array, divided according to the respective price.

Here some example code:

```
library (quantmod)
symbols <- c("NVDA", "AAPL", "NFLX")
getSymbols(symbols, env = stocksEnv <- new.env())

abc <- eapply(stocksEnv, function(x) head(x))
```

I thought something like this list, but for the respective price not the stock.

Thank you already for your answer(s)!

Comment: When posting code based on code in another post the original post should be linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your code:

```
FF <- c("Cl", "Op", "Hi", "Lo")
ABC <- lapply(FF, function(ff) Reduce("merge", lapply(abc, ff)))
names(ABC) <- FF
```